# MC68k clearing ds.w labels

Tags: assembly, motorola

I have a question about to how clear values of this size.
I have 20 word sized values (16bits) and they're stored at address $3000. I have to organize the values into good and bad values. Good values get stored at $3300 and bad values at $3600. My assignment calls them Table of values and that I should clear the table of values for the good and bad values at the beginning of my program to prepare for repeat runs. But I'm unsure how to clear it.

```
      ORG $3000
SCORE DS.W 1
      ORG $3300
GOOD DS.W 1
      ORG $3600
BAD  DS.W 1
```

Not sure how I'm supposed to clear ALL the values at label GOOD and BAD

Comment: It would probably involve a loop. I suggest that you download the [M68000 Programmer's Reference Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf) and start going through the available instructions to see which ones you could use to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How is this for an example?

```
move #20 d0
lea GOOD, a0
loop:
clr.w (a0)+
dbeq d0, loop
```

You might also want to make the tables bigger than 1 word.